# Calling independent network calls in parallel with RxJava and handling error

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am trying to call multiple network calls(5 in total) ,each is independent of the others. I know how to call network calls in chain with RxJava. But by calling in chain, if there is an error in calling 3rd or 4th network call, the rest of the calls will not be executed. So I want the rest of the network calls to continue to be executed even when the former calls failed. Is there a way to achieve the solution for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, you can use onErrorResumeNext. example of my code :

`primaryMenuFetcher.getMenu()
                .observeOn(uiScheduler)
                .flatMap { menuItems ->
                    onView {
                        primaryMenu = menuItems
                        setPrimaryMenuList(primaryMenu)
                    }
                    return@flatMap model.getPromotions()
                }
                .onErrorResumeNext { return@onErrorResumeNext model.getPromotions() }
                .observeOn(uiScheduler)
                .doFinally { onView { hideProgressBar() } }
                .subscribe({ fetchedLeagues ->
                    onView {
                        featuredLeagues = fetchedLeagues
                        showPopularLeagues()
                        setPopularLeaguesList(featuredLeagues)
                    }
                }, {
                    showError()
                })`

There is also other Rx2 error handling options. Refer documentation

Comment: I'll try with it. Thank u

Comment: No problem, ask if need more help. If everything okay, please mark as answered :)

Comment: Why did you removed answered flag?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the best things here would be [mergeDelayError](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html). This will delay the errors until all observables completed or errored.

This would be one option:

```
Observable.mergeDelayError(
     obs1.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
     obs2.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
     //...
 )
 .subscribe();
```

The `subscribeOn` is more to guarantee that the requests run in parallel. I don't know if the `io` scheduler is the most suitable in this scenario, but it has been working for me.

If the stream errors, you'll get a composite exception with each problem that occurred for each individual observable. If you need to check these individually you can look at this exception.

Comment: What do you mean? I posted the code in the answer. What else would you need?